# Как убрать текст, что выходит за границы блока?

Tags: css, flexbox, width

**Задача** заключаеться в том что нужно убрать перенос! Блок в котором лежит заголовок имеет высоту *28px* и ширину *100%*. Пробовал сделать через `white-space: nowrap;` но при сжатии, блок с заголовком "лезет" на изображение.
Каркас делаю *flexbox*'ами. Поэтому если знаете решение с их использованием, будет очень кстати!
[image: Пример на скрине]

Comment: line-height: 28px; overflow: hidden;

Comment: Да, но тогда текст заголовок опускаеться ниже. Не посередине, а снизу уже расположен.

Comment: Значит у вас например padding задан для блока

Comment: Действительно, Спасибо ;)

Comment: Как быть, если у меня для блока этого заголовка есть ::before и при использовании overflow: hidden; он исчезает, так как за его границами!

Comment: Например можно реализовать стрелку слева другим образом. Градиентами например, или svg.

Comment: Тоесть наилучшый способ переделать стрелку с border-left, на другое. Правильно понял?!

Comment: Ну да, все верно.

Comment: Окей, принял. Спасибо за помочь! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ пользователя [Andrey Fedorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208243/):

`line-height: 28px; overflow: hidden;`

Если у вашего блока есть псевдоэлементы *::before* или *::after*, 
то учтите, что их тоже спрячет *overflow*